# Permuted Matrix Multiplication in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix with entries out of order. As an example, `A = [a1, a2]` is the typical matrix with partitions a1 and a2 (a1 and a2 aren't necessarily scalars but can be subarrays). My matrix is instead in the order `A = [a2, a1]`.

I still want to perform normal matrix multiplication as if A was in the correct order. Is there a way to do this without copying?

The use case for this is multiplying over a circular buffer. I've been trying to avoid using numpy.roll for the buffer. Often times, the circular buffer is fragmented, but I just want to multiply across since I know where the buffer fragments.

It just seems like no matter what I do, I'll end up having to make an allocation of elements equal in size to the final matrix product because multiplying by any partition of A will still have the same number of columns, so the final dimensions won't change since A1 (the part of A that will multiply partition 1) will be `m x k1` and the partition will be `k1 x n` (where k1 is the number of rows in the partition).

`np.matmul` doesn't seem to have an option to add to an existing array instead of overwriting one. It just bothers me since there shouldn't be another allocation required since the elements are just in a different order. I figured I could just map the elements accordingly, but it's been proving more difficult than that.

Example:

```py
data = np.empty((10, 3))
buffer = CircularBuffer(data)

for i in range(10):
   data.push(i)

# buffer now reads [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], ...]

data.push(-1)
data.push(-2)
# buffer overwrites oldest element
# reads [[-1, -1, -1], [-2, -2, -2], [2, 2, 2], ...] 

A = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 10)

# We want this to perform A @ [[2, 2, 2], ..., [-1, -1, -1], [-2, 2, -2]]
#                              buf_start                      buf_end
# Unfortunately, the buffer is out of order!
A @ buffer
```

Clearly there are two "partitions" in the buffer. From the start of the buffer to the end of the storage element `[[2, 2, 2], ...]` and from the start of the storage element to the end of the buffer `[[-1, -1, -1], [-2, -2, -2]]`.

We know the order they ought to be in (shown in the code), but we want the multiplication to be expressed in the order of the BUFFER not the raw data itself and I'd like to avoid copying.

Comment: Could you please add a reproducible input so that others can help you with a solution. thanks!

Comment: "I still want to perform normal matrix multiplication". You perhaps missed mentioning the matrices that you want to multiply together.

Comment: "since X will be m x k1". What does X refer to here?

Comment: I've added an example. Sorry for the lack of clarity everyone. Also X was a typo, I meant A, but yeah, updated for clarity.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the rows of `buffer` are a permutation, or a more general subset (or even a superset with duplicates).  It's different from the original.  The columns of A` have to be in the matching order.. when doing `A@B` the current values matter, not the history..

Comment: Are the out-of-order chunks of A swapped vertically or horizontally? It's not clear.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica They are swapped horizontally. The rows are out of order. For a buffer of shape `(x, y, z)` the first index `x` is used to determine the position in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The posted question mentions that `A = [a1, a2]` where `a1` and `a2` could be sub-arrays rather than scalars.

Accordingly, for my working example, I defined `A.shape` as `(10, 3, 2)`.
As per `numpy` rules of matrix multiplication (applicable to `np.matmul()` as well as to `@` operator as well as to `np.dot()`), for `A @ buffer` to be valid, the last dimension of `A` must match the second-last dimension of `buffer`. Hence, I defined `buffer.shape` as `(10, 2, 3)`. (Note the difference with the shape of `A`)

Here's my initialization of `A` and `buffer`:

```
A      = np.arange(60).reshape (10, 2, 3)
buffer = -1 * np.arange(60).reshape (10, 3, 2)
```

Then, with these shapes, `A @ buffer` would have the shape of `(10, 2, 2)`. Hence, to hold the result of the matrix multiplication, I define the array `my_result` as:

```
my_result = np.empty(A.shape[:-1]+buffer.shape[-1:]) # To hold the result of A @ buffer
```

Now, it is mentioned in the question that the rows of `buffer` are out of order.

Let `k` be the index (on `axis0` of `buffer`) at which the "buffer is fragmented / partitioned". (Therefore, `0 <= k <= 9`).

```
k = 2
```

Then, instead of performing the matrix multiplication between `A` and `buffer` in one go, it can be done in two steps, as below:

```
np.matmul(A[:k], buffer[-k:], out=my_result[:k])     # Fills a part of my_result
np.matmul(A[k:], buffer[:-k], out=my_result[k:])     # Fills the other part of my_result
```

**Testing:**

```
my_result1 = np.matmul(A, np.roll(buffer, k, axis=0))
np.array_equal(my_result, my_result1)
```

**Output:**

> True

To summarize, what we're doing here is:

- Allocate an un-initialized array `my_result` to hold the result of `matmul()`
- Invoke `matmul()` twice, each time, passing a different slice of `my_result` as the value of the `out` parameter of `matmul()`, and taking care to index `A` and `buffer` in the right way.

As far as I can see, there's no redundant data-copy involved here, unless you count `np.empty()` as some kind of data-copy. It's just the original matrix multiplication happening in two instalments.

Comment: I believe the elements of A are supposed to be out of order along the other axis.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is correct, but I wonder if the same effect could be achieved by transposing and un-transposing. Does transposing use memory?

Comment: @EmmyChow -- `np.transpose(a)` creates a new `numpy` array that uses the same underlying memory block as its input `a`. Regarding your problem description, you have clearly mentioned that, for the purpose of the multiplication `A @ buffer`, even though the row `[-1,-1,-1]` and row `[-2,-2,-2]` of `buffer` are present at index `0` and index `1` (on axis `0`) resp., you wanted the multiplication to behave as though they were present at index `-2` and index `-1`, respectively. In other words, the "out-of-order" issue is along axis `0`, and not axis `1`. That is exactly what my answer addresses.

Comment: @EmmyChow - Everywhere, you have only mentioned that the ROWS are out of order. Nowhere have you mentioned that the elements within a row are out of order. My answer is based on that description. What is the issue?

Comment: @fountainhead Yes the rows are out of order, though, I'm not really getting your solution to work. I keep getting dimension mismatches. Can you put up a complete example somewhere to show me?

Comment: @EmmyChow - I have edited my answer to include complete code for my working example. Note that since your question skipped several details, such as the exact shapes of `A` and `buffer`, I have had to make assumptions. My edited answer elaborates all assumptions made. Hope this clarifies. Pls let me know your thoughts (even if it turns out that my understanding of your intentions is completely off-target).

Comment: I think it was a good attempt, though, it doesn't work for what I want. The main use case was to do 2D-2D matrix multiplication. If A was (3, 3) and buffer was (3, 3) with permuted rows. Unfortunately, the more I look, I think there is no good general solution. Thank you though.